# Azure Function App error: Function Site Name is over 32 Characters long

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am testing a dedicated plan Function App (v4) and under the Function's "Diagnose and solve problems", I see the error:

> Function Site Name is over 32 Characters long

This doesn't make sense because the Function's name is exactly 32 characters long.

As a test, I followed the recommendation and set `AzureFunctionsWebHost__hostid = "ah91koqh801sss"`.

The original error is still reported and now a new error appears:

> Host id explicitly set in configuration. This is not a recommended configuration and may lead to unexpected behavior.

I've reviwed the MS documentation and don't see any issue. What is the actual solution here?

Answer (score 0):

> Function Site Name is over 32 Characters long

A host ID must be between 1 and 32 characters with only lowercase letters, numbers, and dashes (should not be consecutive).

> Host id explicitly set in configuration. This is not a recommended configuration and may lead to unexpected behavior.

- This is a warning that arises when providing an explicit Host ID to override default generated Host ID.
- It happens if you use the same storage account between different Function Apps using the same Host ID including local development cases.

***Note: To avoid Host ID collision, you have to create a new storage account along with the function app with unique names***.

I have created a Function App with 32 characters with a new storage account and .NET(Windows) as runtime stack using App Service plan (dedicated plan).

- It worked without any issues.

[image]

[image]

To override the Host Id, added the application setting `AzureFunctionsWebHost__hostid` in Function App=>Settings=>Configuration=>Application Settings:

- You can also use `AzureFunctionsWebHost:hostid` to override the Host ID of **Windows Function app**.

[image]

- Can see the **Host ID** changed successfully in the Application Insights of function app:

[image]

**References:**

[Host IDs · Azure/azure-functions-host Wiki (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Host-IDs#host-id-collisions)

Comment: It seems that you're just reiterating what I've already tried, and not responding to the actual post. As stated in the OP, I'm already overriding the Host ID and Azure is still complaining.

Comment: I have explained about the warning you are getting when overriding the HostID. You can also find the info about the warning in the reference link I have provided.

Comment: In the post I said I have already implemented `AzureFunctionsWebHost__hostid` as per the documentation. The issue is the original warning still exists, as well as receiving a new error. Your post didn't actually answer the question I asked at the end of the post.

Comment: Are you using newly created storage account or existing one?

Comment: Same storage account. Function App has been restarted, code deployed again/

Comment: Can you create a new storage account and function app and deploy again?